# Geometric node to launch curves from faces

Tags: geometry-nodes

I made digital globe (sphere). I need a few circles on the globe and from each circle go curves of light in different directions on a sphere. I created  a new sphere and take a few faces, then I used instance on points node to change each face on circle. But I can't understand how to make curves of light from this circles. Or may be you know a better way?[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way is using this node setup: it is just a circle with instance on points with arc:

[image]

[image]

and then you can instance that on a sphere like this:

[image]

[image]

you can animate each spline (via trim curve) like this:

[image]

[image]